# Why won’t the aperture adjust on my Sony A camera?

Tags: autofocus, aperture, lens-design, diy, sony-alpha

I recently bought a telezoom objective without built-in AF. I did not bother because my camera has an AF which could handle the focus on such lenses.

I always had used lenses with built-in AF so I did not know that this lens would not work; it did not. There was something wrong with the mechanics so I tore it apart to evaluate the problem. I did not find it so I put it back together.

After this, though, the aperture of my lenses did not adjust according to the settings I set on the camera. In fact, the aperture does not do anything. It turns out there is a metal ring responsible for the aperture (see picture). I don't know what mechanism would move it so that it will close and open the aperture.

Could you help me with this? Thank you!

[image: Ring responsible for the aperture]

Comment: You tore what apart? Lens or camera?

Comment: Which camera are you using? And which lens? You say "the aperture of my lenses did not adjust according to the settings I set on the camera". Are you able to take photos? Are they correctly exposed? What aperture setting does the Exif data indicate? Just to confirm - you know that the actual lens aperture is not adjusted until the moment the photo is taken, regardless of the setting on the camera?

Comment: The "pin" protruding from the rear of the lens, which is engaged by the camera body for manually changing the aperture - can you manipulate this yourself? When the lens is not mounted, you should be able to move this pin, and the aperture should open/close. Putting a rear lens cap on the lens normally opens the aperture fully - visible when looking in the front of the lens as you mount the rear lens cap.